# copy JavaScript object values into a associate array in javascript

Tags: javascript

the values from a JavaScript object into a associative array. Below is a sample of what i am trying to do.

```
$(window).load(function() {
  items = [
    {title: 'Paint pots'},
    {title: 'Polka dots'},
    {title: 'Pebbles'}
  ];
  var test;       
  for(var item in items) {
    test=[{name:item.title}];
  }
  for(item in test) {
    alert(item.title);
  }
});
```

But the code does not function properly. Can any one point out the mistake here?

---

Here is a link to my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MACxav/9xJdD/

Comment: I think there nothing like Associative Array in javascirpt.Am i right?

Comment: ...Isn't `test` a single-property object after your code executes?

Comment: @zerkms: Sorry about the typho. Yet i still get undefined.

Comment: @PrashantShilimkar well objects are associative arrays `{key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}` (at least if you use the definition that one key can hold one value)

Comment: Actually, an "associative array" is pretty much the same as an "array-like object" but should called it as object only

Comment: @MacleanPinto: your `items` is already an array. an array of objects.

Comment: @abhitalks: The above is a simple version of my requirement. The actual object is a shopping cart object will has service functions which can be used to modify the cart. I am simple creating cart object which only contains data, for viewing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some mistakes that are causing problems

`var test;` -- You're not initializing `test`

`for(var item in items)` -- Each `item` here is a key, so it's 0,1,2. It's not an item from the items array as some might expect.

`test=[{name:item.title}];` -- You're overwriting the test variable here, not adding the item to the array, or (if that's what you intend) assigning `item.title` to the `name` key

`for(item in test)` -- Same as before, the `item` here is not an object but the key.

**[edit, merging in my earlier answer, with some edits]**

The start of your code-snippet (`$(window).load`) indicates you're using jQuery, so I'd use the `each` function* on the jQuery object.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  items = [
    {title: 'Paint pots'},
    {title: 'Polka dots'},
    {title: 'Pebbles'}
  ];
  var test = []; /* initialize as array */
  $.each(items, function(idx, item) 
  {
    test.push({name:item.title}); /* add to array rather than overwrite */
  })
  $.each(test, function(idx, item) {
    console.log(item.name); /* use console instead of alert, because we're not savages */
  })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2JwpL/

(* Some browsers do support a `for each (variable in object)` construct, but it's now [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in).  A `for(variable of object)` [is proposed for EcmaScript 6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) )

Comment: Sorry for the late response. You cleared a lot of my misunderstanding's about associate array.

Comment: I would accept this answer, simply because it points out my mistakes instead of directly providing a solution.

Comment: @MacleanPinto Thanks for your comments. At your suggestion I've merged my answers.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:** Your code is creating an array of a arrays (each containing a single object). Except you overwrite `test`, so it's a single-object array of one single-object array.

This runs the same way as your code, but with the desired effect. Note that towards the end, the code is more difficult to understand:

```
items = [ // array of three objects
    {title: 'Paint pots'},
    {title: 'Polka dots'},
    {title: 'Pebbles'}
];

var test = new Array(); // an array

for(var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
    test[i]=[{name:items[i].title}];  // test[i] = an ARRAY with a single object
}                                     // which has a single property

for(var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    alert(test[i][0].name); // get test's i-th array's first item's name property
}
```

[**Demo of complicated code**](http://jsfiddle.net/fgqQ2/)

**Solution:** Create an array of *objects* (not single-element arrays):

```
items = [
    {title: 'Paint pots'},
    {title: 'Polka dots'},
    {title: 'Pebbles'}
];

var test = new Array();       

for(var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
    test[i]={name:items[i].title}; // put one OBJECT into test[i]
}

for(var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    alert(test[i].name);
}
```

[**Demo of simple code**](http://jsfiddle.net/fgqQ2/1/)

Sidenote: this doesn't require jQuery.